# Asterisk distribution with very fast deployment

Tags: voip, bare-metal, asterisk

I have zero experiences with Asterisk but need to choose the best bare-metal distribution (running as a VM guest) for my needs.

- Asterisk server will answer calls, auto responder says caller extension number and hangs up
- I'll connect it thru SIP trunk to the Avaya PBX, I can use another H.323 server too if it's possible (because H.323 PBX is on local network, SIP in the another city)
- it's planned for just one concurrent call
- I got a very little time for this task from my boss, so it must be easy and quick solution without need of learning Asterisk and writing configurations
- I prefer very customized install with lot of options because I don't need most of typical PBX features
- google told me about AsteriskNow, TrixBox and Elastix

*What's your recommendation? Hope I've chosen correct site for this question*

Comment: please anybody can tell me which stack exchange site is suitable for this `computer software` question? I would like to do my best to choose the right site!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Elastix. It has a widely support forum with a great newbie corner as they call it found [here](http://www.elastix.org/index.php/en/component/kunena/25-newbies-corner-.html)

We personally also run it on a VM and found that 2 Gigs of ram with 1vcpu was sufficient to get it going. I would advise downloading and installing the 2.3.0 stable version as this has been tested for a few months now with no faults.

The graphical user interface is easy to navigate compared to something like a Atcom PBX etc. Some things to keep in mind however, never put your Elastix internet facing. We installed Elastix with a basic username and password and the server got hacked in 29 minutes. Be sure to follow this [guide](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/elastix/Tutorials_Docs_Manuals/Elastix%25202.0%2520Guides/Elastix%2520_%2520Network%2520Security%2520Guide.pdf&ei=G4mKULbCDNKQhQe_pYCYAg&usg=AFQjCNHeIGXatRTUdsvHjp-H-3FYVZ1v0Q)

and this [one](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http://www.elastix.org/index.php/en/component/kunena/116-security/104336-just-got-hacked.html&ei=G4mKULbCDNKQhQe_pYCYAg&usg=AFQjCNHGOZlklrYi4NbLKGZOCc-9XHQQfQ)

Give your ext's complex and secure passwords. The functionality is limited only by your imagination.

Well supported, possibly very secure and easy to use.

Comment: thank you for your advices and insights, so probably I'll choose Elastix. As this is major for me, can I configure that autoresponder with pure Elastix or is there any additional plugins/work needed?

Comment: Auto responder? You will be looking at recordings. You can them add them as announcements to your IVR's that you create

Comment: I'm going to resolve this task again and still have no clue how to do it. About recordings, no I need TTS system, no recordings, I can't record thousands of exts with their number and usernames.